# Feathers.js + socket.io - Filter service updates by ID

Tags: socket.io, feathersjs

I'm trying to listen for updates on an 'event' service. I don't need to know about all updates that are occurring on the 'event' service, just the ones with a specific id.

```
socket.on('event updated', (rEvent) => {
      console.log('Got an updated Event!', rEvent);
});
```

The above code will listen for any update on the 'event' service and it works...I get everything.

However I'd like to listen to the updates for say 'event/34' ... 34 being the event id

I've tried something like:

```
socket.on('event/34 updated', (rEvent) => {
     console.log('Got an updated Event!', rEvent);
});
```

but that doesn't work.

What's the proper way to listen to updates to a service based on the id?

Comment: @Spiderman good idea but thats not it either

Answer (score 0):

Determining what events are being sent to which client is what [event filters](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/events.html#event-filtering) are for. So you will somehow have to determine if the user that belongs to the `connection` is listening to the event id or not:

```
app.service('events').filter('updated', function(data, connection, hook) {
  if(checkIfUserListensToEventId(connection.user, event)) {
    return data;
  }

  return false;
});
```

In general, server side filters should only determine if the user is *allowed* to see the data. Events are relatively cheap and it is much easier to determine on the client if the data should be used or just ignored (instead of having to somehow statefully keeping track of it on the server).

Side note: Feathers v3 will [support rooms/channels](https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers/issues/388) to make event dispatching more performant.

Comment: I don't have a 'user' concept (not yet anyways) so connection.user is undefined. The 'events' are public, anyone can listen to updates. However, I like the proposed rooms/channels feature in v3 so for now I can filter on the client (based on the id) and I'll wait till v3 hits beta